# Why threads not switching?

Tags: java, multithreading

I want to get a file contains a letter from other files in random order. I must to do it with Threads. And I don't know why I have in output file content from 1 file, after it content from 2 file and after that content from 3 file. I have Main:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
    for(int i=1;i<args.length; i++) {
        new Thread1( args[i], args[0]).start();
    }
}
```

And class Thread1:

```
public class Thread1 extends Thread {
    String path;
    FileWriter fw;
    private String desc;
    public Thread1( String path, String desc) {
        super();
        this.desc=desc;
        this.path=path;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        FileReader f = null;
        try {
             f = new FileReader(path);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        int c;
        try {
            fw = new FileWriter(desc, true);
            while((c = f.read()) != -1) {
                fw.write(c);
            }
            fw.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Please, explain me, why it don't work in way, what I think it should be work.

Comment: You must `start()` the thread after creating it.

Comment: I have it after creating object in first code.

Comment: What output are you getting? What output do you expect? Can you provide more details so we can replicate this issue on our own systems?

Comment: Example:I have 4 files. First file is empty. 2 file has: abcdef. 3 file: ghijkl. 4 file: mnoprst. I have it in that order in output file. I want to have it randomly. Text in files is longer that this example. I expect something like gfdsjayfiudsafui :)

Comment: they are switching, but not every nanosecond (rather, 10-50 milliseconds). So for every processor visit, a thread can do a lot of work.

Comment: You're having a bunch of threads all open different FileWriters to the same file and try to write to it at the same time. That simply won't work, pretty much anything could happen depending on in what order the CPU gives the threads time. Instead, have one synchronized FileWriter that all of your threads write to.

Comment: Ok.. I create variable in Main FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(args[0]); give it to Thread1 by constructor, but it throws error: Stream closed. I close writeStream after while loop.

Comment: Like I said, it has to be synchronized. In this case, one of your threads probably closed the writer before your other threads were done with it. You should consult a tutorial on multithreading principles.

Comment: I know how to synchonize (in theory). I put line fw.write(c); into synchronized (fw), where fw = FileWriter, but it still throw that exception..

Comment: Can you write me sample code, how it can be done?

Answer (score 1):

> Please, explain me, why it don't work in way, what I think it should be work.

Your problem is that all of your threads are appending to the same file but using different `FileWriter` instances.  This sounds like it would work but they are all overwriting each other.  When you open a file for appending it opens it and positions the write marker at the end of the file.  When two threads do this, they both will be at the same marker.  If thread #1 writes a character then thread #2 will write a character and overwrite the first.

You could use a single `FileWriter` and share it with each of your threads.  Then you `synchronize` on it for mutex purposes and do the write.

```
public Thread1( String path, String desc, FileWriter fw) {
    this.fw = fw;
    ...
}
...
// when you write to it, you will need to synchronize on the writer
sychronized (fw) {
   fw.write(c);
}
// don't close it in the threads but close it later after you have joined with
// the threads
```

Another option is to share a `PrintStream` which is already `synchronized` internally.

Comment: Hi, thanks for response :) I have that what you wrote, but it throws a java.io.IOException: Stream closed. I closed it after for loop in Main. It is bad place?

Comment: @user3025978 You should wait for your threads to finish before closing the stream.

Comment: Yes @user3025978, you need to wait for your threads to finish before closing it.  You can use `thread.join()` to join with each of the threads in turn.  You might want to look into `ExecutorService` classes.

Comment: How? I write wait() and notify() - http://pastebin.com/kfh1SUWM but it throw java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException... When I change to PrintStream I have invalid output - only some letters, not all letters.

Comment: Not sure @user3025978. You are going to have to do some more research or ask more questions about each of those problems.